# What would be the best approach for merging arrays while keeping their respective index orders?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have got 3 dummy arrays :

```
const arr1 = [{id: '1a', title: 'abc'}, {id: '2b', title: 'def'}];
const arr2 = [{type: 1, body: 'Hello'}, {type: 2, title: 'Hi}];
const arr3 = [{name: 'Jack', lastname: 'Burton'}, {name: 'David', lastname: 'Lo Pan'}];
```

Like I tried to express in the title, I would like to merge and sort them by keeping their own orders, like this :

```
[{id: '1a', title: 'abc'},{type: 1, body: 'Hello'},{name: 'Jack', lastname: 'Burton'},{id: '2b', title: 'def'},{type: 2, title: 'Hi}, {name: 'David', lastname: 'Lo Pan'}]
```

I cannot find any reasonable approach in term of performance and amount of code ... any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all of your arrays in a container array called `arrs`, and then use `.flatMap()` on one of the arrays such as the first, this will give you the indexes (0, then 1) of your arrays. Then you can use an inner `.map()` to map over all your arrays to take the object from the index your outer flatMap is on from all of your arrays:

```js
const arr1 = [{id: '1a', title: 'abc'}, {id: '2b', title: 'def'}];
const arr2 = [{type: 1, body: 'Hello'}, {type: 2, title: 'Hi'}];
const arr3 = [{name: 'Jack', lastname: 'Burton'}, {name: 'David', lastname: 'Lo Pan'}];

const arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
const res = arr1.flatMap((_, i) => arrs.map(arr => arr[i]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = [{id: '1a', title: 'abc'}, {id: '2b', title: 'def'}];
const arr2 = [{type: 1, body: 'Hello'}, {type: 2, title: 'Hi'}];
const arr3 = [{name: 'Jack', lastname: 'Burton'}, {name: 'David', lastname: 'Lo Pan'}];

const res = arr1.flatMap((val, i) => [val, arr2[i], arr3[i]]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should merge first, then sort.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: '1a', title: 'abc' },
  { id: '2b', title: 'def' },
];

const arr2 = [
  { type: 1, body: 'Hello' },
  { type: 2, title: 'Hi' },
];

const arr3 = [
  { name: 'Jack', lastname: 'Burton' },
  { name: 'David', lastname: 'Lo Pan' },
];

const merged = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];

const sorted = merged.sort();

console.log(sorted);
```